# Replace URL in markdown files in python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, markdown

I have big markdown file. Is there any way to change `/foo` in my url by `/bla`. That is, I want to replace

```
[text](/foo/some-long-url/a.html)
```

for

```
[text](/bla/some-long-url/a.html)
```

(all ocurrences).

I know I could compile markdown file to html and use html parsers (like BeautifulSoup) to do that. But I want to do that, on the source file.

Prefered python or shell solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you can always replace "/foo" to "/bla" directly in the source using sed?

```
sed 's/\/foo/\/bla/' source.md >> destination.md
```

If it catches anything unwanted, you can just tweak the regular expression a bit to be more specific.

Comment: I recommend to wait with an answer until the questioner has shown what he has tried so far and where he has encountered problems.